# STM32 Memory layout and adressing

Tags: stm32

could anyone please explain how does memory layout works on STM32, for example I am using STM32F205RCT6 which say it has **256Kbyte** of FLASH.

If I understand it correctly it means I cannot use memory past **Sector 5.**, because I would violate 256Kb size, is that correct?

Datasheet image below ([link to datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00225773-stm32f205xx-stm32f207xx-stm32f215xx-and-stm32f217xx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf))

[image: S]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access as much memory as you have.

If you have 256Kbyte flash you can access at 0x8000000 - 0x803FFFF

When you erase the sector you can only access Sector 0, Sector 1,Sector 2,Sector 3,Sector 4, Sector 5 as sum of sizes of those sectors is 256kbyte (rather simple math)

```
16 + 16 + 16 + 16 + 64 + 128 = 256
S0 + S1 + S2 + S3 + S5 + S5
```

Comment: So "yes" then :)

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that the datasheet is used for a large variety of models. The model that you are using have only `256KB`, but other models have up to `1MB`, that's why the datasheet shows so many sectors.

Comment: If the datasheet is shown for various models, then how can you fund the details on your exact model? Isn't that the whole point of a datasheet?